# Firebase Functions print an object to the console

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have this code on the Firebase cloud using functions

```
peopleDataBase.orderByChild("mCalculateFaceSizeWidth")
                        .endAt(mCalculateFaceSizeWidth())
                        .limitToLast(1)
                        .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                       var  person = {
                                "name":snapshot.val().name,
                                "age":snapshot.val().age,
                                "id":snapshot.val().id,
                                "children":snapshot.val().children,
                                "address":snapshot.val().address,
                                "image":snapshot.val().image
                            }

                            if(key != snapshot.key){
                                people += person;
                                key = snapshot.key;
                                console.log("The entire people list:",people);
                            }

                        });
```

I am trying to print the people object to the console, I have searched for an hour using JSON.stringify and String even $scope and other methods, nothing worked.
In the log on the cloud I am getting

```
2017-07-11T07:55:54.593Z I status: The entire people list: [object Object]
```

Eventually I want to send the object back to the mobile device but I want to make sure I see the data inside.
Ideas?

Thanks
Eran

Comment: well the log is true your array have 2 object, object can not be parsed directly you can use `JSON.stringify(people);`

Comment: I already tried it, did not work.
I tried this console.log(JSON.stringify(people));
I am getting: 
2017-07-11T09:13:39.483Z I status: "[object Object]"

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue. I had to print it without string concatenation:

```
console.log("The entire people list:");
console.log(people);
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```js
console.log("The entire people list:", JSON.stringify(people));
```

Answer (score -1):

just `console.log` `snap.val()` to see the response.  Add `if(snap.val().whateverProperty` logic.

Comment: The snap.val() is working, I have already checked that, but after adding multiple person to the people object I wanted to print that to the log, apparently not all things that javascript support you can run on the firebase functions .
but thanks for the input.

Comment: is the `.limitToLast(1)` returning a single record?

Comment: Yes it does. Single person

Comment: so if you want to retrieve multiple fetch the parent node, right?

Comment: There is a tiny right arrow in most browser consoles that allows you to expand an object and see it's properties/methods. Is that not there? [object][object] usually renders in the DOM. The console should give you an expand button.